# IE 11 Flexbox breaks when one column is set to display:none

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a setup like this:

```
<div style="display:flex;">
    <div style="flex:1 1 auto; max-width:1176px">
    <div>
     <div style="flex: 1 1 auto; max-width:440px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

but if I have display none to the second div Like this:

```
<div style="display:flex;">
    <div style="flex:1 1 auto; max-width:1176px">
    <div>
     <div style="flex: 1 1 auto; max-width:440px; display:none">
    </div>
</div>
```

the first div collapses to 400px

(using inline styles here just for simplicity)

Comment: Please note that flexbox is not fully supported on IE 11: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Not seeing a problem in IE11. Try a closing tag on the first div.

Comment: Its generally ok. As it says though it  a bit buggy https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my side, Could you capture a screenshot to explain this issue?